# Auth token not being returned in middleware handler

Tags: mongodb, go, http-headers

I'm trying to write a function that checks my header for an auth token and also my db for if it exists. Problem is, I keep this `mongo: no documents in result` error.

This is what checks for the header.

```golang
func APIAuth(endpoint func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        accessToken := r.Header.Get("x-api-key")

        // Check token in db
        usersCollection := client.Database("cities-nighthack").Collection("users")
        filter := bson.D{
            primitive.E{
                Key: "token", Value: accessToken,
            },
        }

        var user User
        err := usersCollection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&user)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            http.Error(w, `Unauthorized access`, http.StatusUnauthorized)
        } else {
            // next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            endpoint(w, r)
        }
    })
}
```

The route within main calls the handler like so

```golang
r.Handle("/suggest", APIAuth(searchCity)).Methods("GET")
```

The `User` struct is formatted as such:

```golang
type User struct {
    Email       string `json:"email"`
    AccessToken string `json:"token"`
}
```

[image: Headers for Postman GET request]

The headers in my postman request look like this

I know for a fact that the token exists in the db, so am I checking the header wrong or something?

Comment: Have you tried adding a debug log to see if `r.Header` contains the X-Api-Key header as expected?

Comment: I ran a small `log.WithFields()` right after the declaration it seems like it does contain the token. The console printed the info correctly.
`INFO[0060] Access token is here                          token=084d412c63f873244dd1b73edf11d1b953996d8493fd428de1714928b74914ea`

Comment: Ah, found the issue. My `Key` within the filter was of a different string than the one in my DB so I was looking for a field that didn't exist. Thank you though, the debug helped me out.